# Access one item from a dict and store it into a variable

Tags: python, flask, uuid

I am trying to get all the "uuid"'s from an API, and the issue is that it is stored into a dict (I think). Her is how it looks on the API:

```
{"guild": {
        "_id": "5eba1c5f8ea8c960a61f38ed",
        "name": "Creators Club",
        "name_lower": "creators club",
        "coins": 0,
        "coinsEver": 0,
        "created": 1589255263630,
        "members":
            [{  "uuid": "db03ceff87ad4909bababc0e2622aaf8",
                "rank": "Guild Master",
                "joined": 1589255263630,
                "expHistory": {
                "2020-06-01": 280,
                "2020-05-31": 4701,
                "2020-05-30": 0,
                "2020-05-29": 518,
                "2020-05-28": 1055,
                "2020-05-27": 136665,
                "2020-05-26": 34806}}]
        }
    }
```

Now I am interested in the "uuid" part there, and take note: There is multiple players, it can be 1 to 100 players, and I am going to need every UUID.

Now I have done this in my python to get the UUID's displayed on the website:
try:

```
f = requests.get(
            "https://api.hypixel.net/guild?key=[secret]&id=" + guild).json()
        guildName = f["guild"]["name"]
        guildMembers = f["guild"]["members"]
        members = client.getPlayer(uuid=guildMembers) #this converts UUID to player names
        #I need to store all uuid's in variables and put them at "guildMembers"
```

And that gives me all the "UUID codes", and I will be using `client.getPlayer(uuid=---)` to convert the UUID into the Player Names. I have to loop through each "UUID" into that code `client.getPlayer(uuid=---)` . But first of I need to save the UUID'S in variables, I have been doing `members.uuid` to access the UUID on my HTML file, but I don't know how you do the `.uuid` part in python

If you need anything else, just comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehension is a powerful concept:

```
members = [client.getPlayer(member['uuid']) for member in guildMembers]
```

**Edit:**
If you want to insert the names back into your data (in guildMembers),
use a dictionary comprehension with {uuid: member_name,} format:

```
members = {member['uuid']: client.getPlayer(uuid=member['uuid']) for member in guildMembers}
```

Than you can update guildMembers with your results:

```
for member in guildMembers:
    guildMembers[member]['name'] = members[member['uuid']]
```

Comment: `client.getPlayer` needs to take two arguments, first is `uuid=` and second is the UUID.

Comment: this is the `client.getPlayer()` from their documentation (Hypixthon is the module name, forgot to say that.) `client.getPlayer(uuid="player uuid")`

Comment: it takes two arguments in the getPlayer(), `uuid=` and then UUID to that Minecraft account. When doing this you shared here, it asks for the second argument, or it asks for `uuid=`, tried adding it in, but no luck!

Comment: hm, strange. Didn't work the first time.. works now though, thanks!

Comment: Just a question, how can I store the UUID only in a variable? so without the Client.getPlayer() part? I tried to get the "displayname" inside of the content that gets displayed after doing getPlayer() by doing member["player"]["displayname"], but no luck! So I might need the UUID only. Did this, but no luck `members = [guildMembers['uuid'] for member in guildMembers]`

Comment: it just shows nothing on my website, I can get the uuid's to display only, but cant get the names to display.

Comment: If you want only the uuid; members = [member['uuid'] for member in guildMembers]   Can you tell me what data getPlayer returns ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `guild` is the main dictionary in which a key called `members` exists with a list of "sub dictionaries", you can try

```
uuid = list()
for x in guild['members']:
    uuid.append(x['uuid'])
```

`uuid` now has all the uuids

Answer (score 0):

If i understood situation right, You just need to loop through all received uuids and get  players' data. Something like this:

```
f = requests.get("https://api.hypixel.net/guild?key=[secret]&id=" + guild).json()
guildName = f["guild"]["name"]
guildMembers = f["guild"]["members"]
guildMembersData = dict()  # Here we will save member's data from getPlayer method

for guildMember in guildMembers:
    uuid = guildMember["uuid"]
    memberData = client.getPlayer(uuid=uuid)
    guildMembersData[uuid] = client.getPlayer(uuid=guildMember["uuid"])

print(guildMembersData)  # Here will be players' Data.
```

Comment: what are you using `memberData = client.getPlayer(uuid=uuid)` for? It says  `Unused variable 'memberData'`